# Training and Testing deep CNN with same piece of data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have created a deep CNN from a research paper (using tensorflow) and am now curious if I have done everything correctly. Eventually I want to train and test the CNN on many images, but at the moment I only have one image on hand. **If I was to use this one image as training and testing data, should the CNN always have 100% accuracy**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with only one image to match, you will have a trivial case of perfect accuracy (1-for-1).  However, this is only a "breath of life" test for your model.  All you'll know is that you are functionally capable of running one image through that model; this will tell you nothing (or very little) about your topology's effectiveness with that type of image.

Comment: So if my accuracy is 0% then something must be pretty wrong... Any suggestions or would you have to see the code?

Comment: We would need to see the code and perhaps a trace of the training process.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong.  Did you train to convergence?  What are your criteria of stopping the training?

Comment: Try a few things: (1) Switch to a trivially simple CNN; make sure you can get *something* to identify the image properly.  (2) Check your reported loss function values; did you reach convergence in the training?  (3) Is your initialization constant, or random?  I recommend random.

Comment: I think my problem has to do with data structures I use to store the input and label data. If I train with all zeros I get 100% accuracy. I will post a new question. Thanks.

Comment: You might also consider training on trivial images, such as all black and all white.  Labeling those as different classes would give you another test of functionality.

Comment: Here is a gist of relevant code to this problem: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2d1530046be5ece8ee221a314f6425f. With the knowledge that my input is a 32x32x7 image with a density associated with each pixel and the output should be a 32x32x7 image with a label for each pixel, does this code show why I would be getting a training and testing accuracy of 0%? Thanks.